# How to load more data on recyclerview scroll with JSON API

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I want to load the next page data on the Recyclerview scroll (when the user scrolls to the bottom). I and calling the API again for fetching the next page data and notify the adapter of this, but it seems I am doing something wrong. Please help me with what is wrong with this code.

[This is my previous question where all code pasted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936311/how-to-show-json-objects-included-in-json-array-in-android-recyclerview)

This is Fragment Class.

```
public class LeadsFragment extends Fragment {

    boolean isLoading = false;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LeadsAdapter leadsAdapter;
    ArrayList<LeadModel> rowsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static final String url = "myurl";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leads, container, false);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

                LeadModel leadModelList = gson.fromJson(response, LeadModel.class);
                for (int i = 0; i < leadModelList.getData().size(); i++) {
                    rowsArrayList.add(leadModelList);
                }

                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                leadsAdapter = new LeadsAdapter(getContext(), rowsArrayList, recyclerView);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(leadsAdapter);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        queue.add(stringRequest);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                if (!isLoading) {
                    if (linearLayoutManager != null && linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 10 - 1) {
                        // Last item reached
                        loadMore(); // Note this method
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return view;

    }

    private void loadMore() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url + "?page=2", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

                LeadModel leadModelList = gson.fromJson(response, LeadModel.class);
                for (int i = 0; i < leadModelList.getData().size(); i++) {
                    rowsArrayList.add(leadModelList);
                }
                leadsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                isLoading = false;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: you are doing it is wrong way. Please watch this [video](https://youtu.be/9r-BoGoZWVs). It is not proper way to implement the pagination but it could help you to understand how to implement it. By the way it is in Retrofit

Comment: Helped a little bit. But not solved my problem. Do you have volley library example.

Answer (score 0):

This better work because I haven't used Volley library ever since I started working on android. But this is an example how you can achieve pagination

**In your XML**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/NestedScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/HomeRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/home_recycler_list_layout" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**and in your class**

```
ArrayList<LeadModel> rowsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
SwipeRefreshLayout SwipeDown;
ProgressBar progressBar;
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
int Page = 0;
LeadsAdapter leadsAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.NestedScroll);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
    recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.HomeRecycler);

    nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new 
    NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                Page++;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getData(Page);
            }
        }
    });
 
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    leadsAdapter = new LeadsAdapter(getContext(), rowsArrayList, recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(leadsAdapter);

    getData(Page);
}

private void getData(int Page) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url + "?page="+Page, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // set Progress dialog Visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE if response is success
            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            LeadModel leadModelList = gson.fromJson(response, LeadModel.class);
            for (int i = 0; i < leadModelList.getData().size(); i++) {
                rowsArrayList.add(leadModelList);
            }
            leadsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: I am doing same thing [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950692/how-to-load-more-data-in-recyclerview-on-scroll-using-json-api) but getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10 error

Comment: Yes I tried, getting same error:  Index: 10, Size: 10 error

Comment: please share your api response

Comment: [Here is my all class and api data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936311/how-to-show-json-objects-included-in-json-array-in-android-recyclerview) I am fetching 2nd page data on scroll and updating adapter, but I think onBindView position is not updating.